# Search data using searchbar from tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar

i m new in IOS developer.my problem is i want to search data using item name.when i type B than B start data is display.here this is my nsmutable array value.

```
(
        {
        counts = 0;
        "drycleaning_price" = 10;
        id = 2;
        imagename = "";
        "iron_price" = 16;
        name = Bedsheet;
        "wash_price" = 15;
        "washiron_price" = 14;
    },
        {
        counts = 0;
        "drycleaning_price" = 12;
        id = 3;
        imagename = d;
        "iron_price" = 16;
        name = "Coat(Man)";
        "wash_price" = 14;
        "washiron_price" = 13;
    },
        {
        counts = 0;
        "drycleaning_price" = 15;
        id = 4;
        imagename = f;
        "iron_price" = 10;
        name = "Jeans(Man)";
        "wash_price" = 12;
        "washiron_price" = 16;
    },
        {
        counts = 0;
        "drycleaning_price" = 14;
        id = 3;
        imagename = "";
        "iron_price" = 12;
        name = "Pants(Kid)";
        "wash_price" = 18;
        "washiron_price" = 17;
    },
        {
        counts = 0;
        "drycleaning_price" = 15;
        id = 2;
        imagename = s;
        "iron_price" = 10;
        name = "Pants(Man)";
        "wash_price" = 13;
        "washiron_price" = 12;
    },
        {
        counts = 0;
        "drycleaning_price" = 12;
        id = 1;
        imagename = "";
        "iron_price" = 32;
        name = "Pillow Cover";
        "wash_price" = 30;
        "washiron_price" = 15;
    },
```

here this is my screenshot

[image]

here this is my code

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [arrayCounts count];
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    customcell *cell = (customcell *)[self.tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customcell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.txt_value.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.searchResults[indexPath.row][@"counts"]];
cell.lbl_price.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arrayCounts[indexPath.row][@"drycleaning_price"]];
        } else
        {


        cell.txt_value.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arrayCounts[indexPath.row][@"counts"]];
        cell.lbl_title.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arrayCounts[indexPath.row][@"name"]];
cell.lbl_price.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arrayCounts[indexPath.row][@"drycleaning_price"]];
        }
[cell.stepper addTarget:self action:@selector(itemsChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return cell;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    NSPredicate *resultpredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@",self.searchResults];
    self.searchResults=[[arrayCounts valueForKey:@"name" ] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultpredicate];




    NSLog(@"searchlist %@",self.searchResults );
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

i want to search using name.pls help me bro.thank you for advance....

Answer (score -1):

First of all make your array of objects name it ItemClass.
Making an array of object will make your life easy.

Make a class inherited from NSObject class.

Put this in It

```
@interface ItemClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *count;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *dryCleanPrice;

@end
```

Then store your data like this

```
ItemClass *item = [[ItemClass alloc] init];
item.name =@"yourName";
item.dryCleanPrice = @"334";
item.count = @"3";
[arrTempTableData addObject:item];
```

Then use two mutable arrays holding objects of Item class

a. arrTempTableData

b. arrTableData

Then put following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 { static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
customcell *cell = (customcell *)[self.tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customcell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];



ItemClass *item = arrTableData[indexPath.row];

    cell.txt_value.text = item.count;
    cell.lbl_title.text=item.name;
    cell.lbl_price.text=item.dryCleanPrice;

   [cell.stepper addTarget:self action:@selector(itemsChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
return cell;
}
```

then in searchBar

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name beginswith[c] %@ ", searchText];
    self.arrTableData = [self.arrTempTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].mutableCopy;   
    self.arrTableData = self.arrTempTableData.count;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    if(searchText.length == 0){
        self.arrTableData = nil;
        self.arrTableData = self.arrTempTableData.mutableCopy;
    }
```

}

Comment: which array name i will store my array arrTempTableData yaa  arrTableData